# How to get error message from system command in perl (both windows and Unix)

Tags: python, perl

My below perl script (version 5.8.8) is calling python script via system command. Right now only the ERROR_CODE is being retured. How to get error message from system command in perl (both windows and Unix)?

```
@cmd = ("myscript.py");                
my ($exit_code) =  system(@cmd);
```

Comment: At least strong overlap and the answers on SO discussion "Perl: Capturing correct return value from 'system' command" pointed to by @Jean-FrançoisFabre should bring all needed info to the table.